# Issue with javascript parameter

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have an issue with the following code when trying to use the `mColumns` parameter inside an object. The first console log outputs properly, but the one inside the object that is passed to `Backbone.View.extend` doesn't, it outputs undefined.

```
define(["collections/mColumns"],function(mColumns){
        console.log(mColumns);
        return Backbone.View.extend({
                el: "#content",
                events:{
                    'click #addText': "addText"
                },
                initialize: function(mColumns){
                    console.log(mColumns);
                }
            }); 
});
```

However if I create an object beforehand and then pass that object as a parameter it works fine. Both console logs output correctly.

```
define(["collections/mColumns"],function(mColumns){
    console.log(mColumns);
    var obj = {
        el: "#content",
        events:{
            'click #addText': "addText"
        },
        initialize: function(){
            console.log(mColumns);
        }
    }
    return Backbone.View.extend(obj);
});
```

Why is this?

Comment: You do know that you shadowed `mColumns` in the first case, don't you..?

Comment: @RobW you are right, thank you, newbie mistake, if you post it as an answer I'll gladly mark it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the working (second) snippet and the first snippet is that the first snippet shadows the `mColumns` variable. By defining a formal function parameter with the same name, the original variable becomes invisible to code inside the function:

```
define(["collections/mColumns"],function(mColumns){  // <-- mColumns (#1)
    ...
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        ...
        initialize: function(mColumns){              // <-- mColumns (#2)
            console.log(mColumns);                   // <-- Refers to #2
        }
    })
});
```